# Content_Main and Activity_Main in Android Studio 1.4: If I put a button in activity_main, but not content_main, will the java file know about it?

Tags: android-studio

I'm a beginner to android but have done a little with an older version of Android Studio, and in the new version I'm having a lot of trouble getting the java file to find buttons or ImageViews. I'm not sure if it's related to the content_main vs activity_main thing. I'm having trouble finding any answers as to how this works on Google, so I'm just starting here, I want to put a button on the main page of my app and have the java file that correlates to the XML file find it. How do I do this?

Answers online are very vague to me, things like "activity_main.xml will determine how the look of the main activity should be. And on the other hand content_main.xml will determine the contents in the activity_main.xml" does not mean anything to me. Please tell me where to put the button!

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding a button in activity_main rather than content_main it cannot be recognized by your Java file. Not only that is will even not be visible on your app.

Comment: i put button in content_main. i enabled clickable and set onClickListener, but when i run the app it is not responsive. top navBar is but not the buttons in content_main